# Get Error (error=access_denied) while logging in MVC5 application with facebook SDK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth-2.0

I have developed an application with ASP.NET MVC5. I have used Facebook external authentication in my application.
When I debug this application with the "Locallhost" domain, the Facebook login works well but when I publish the application in the main server,the AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo() returns null and it gives me an error like this in the url:

```
http://xxxxx.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?ReturnUrl=%2Fen&error=access_denied#_=_
```

I have set the "Site URL" as "http://xxxx.com" and "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" as "http://xxxx.com/signin-facebook" in the Facebook development console.

My setting in the Startup.Outh.cs file is:

```
var FacebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
        FacebookOptions.AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Facebook_User_Key"];
        FacebookOptions.AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Facebook_Secret_Key"];
        FacebookOptions.Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnAuthenticated = async context =>
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                foreach (var claim in context.User)
                {
                    var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", claim.Key);
                    string claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                    if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"));
                }

            }
        };
        FacebookOptions.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(FacebookOptions);
```

I don't know why the external login does not work only in the server with my main domain name. please help me about this problem.

Comment: Is your app in Development mode? If yes does the user have a role in your app? Are you asking for any permissions that have not been approved?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered pretty much the same symptoms you describe:

**shortly:**

A Facebook authentication worked well on localhost, and after uploading the project to another server (and changing the site URL on Facebook console), authentication did not succeed.

I would recommend you roll back to the MVC template code, and if that works - notice any changes you have made to the middleware code (Startup.Auth.sc).
In particular pay attention to code that interacts with LOCAL configuration, such as Disk I/O and OS permissions for local services.

**My particular case:**

Starting from the Owin/Katana supported Visual Studio template of a WebAPI project, external login was working perfectly with Facebook, Microsoft and Google OAuth middleware, when testing on localhost.

Later I added come code to Startup.Auth.sc because I needed further authentication activity.

So this was the original code:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // see WebAPI template of Visual Studio 2013/2015
        ...
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            appId: 99999999,
            appSecret: *******);
    }
```

and this was replacement:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // see WebAPI template of Visual Studio 2013/2015
        ...
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(GetFacebookAuth());            
    }
    private FacebookAuthenticationOptions GetFacebookAuth()
    {
        string picRequest =
            String.Format("/me/picture?redirect=false&width={0}&height={0}", ProfileInfoClaimsModel.PIC_SIDE_PX);
        var facebookProvider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnAuthenticated = async (context) =>
            {
                var client = new FacebookClient(context.AccessToken);
                dynamic me = client.Get("/me?fields=id,name,locale");
                dynamic mePicture = client.Get(picRequest);

                // storing temporary social profile info TO A LOCAL FOLDER
                // uploading the local folder to a service WITH A LOCAL CREDENTIAL FILE
                ...
            }

        };
        var options = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = 0123456789,
            AppSecret = ******,
            Provider = facebookProvider,
        };
        return options;
    }
```

You may notice that my comments will make the problem obvious - the code points to local resources.

Then I published the project to a virtual server (by Amazon EC2) running Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.5.
From that moment I kept getting `error=access_denied` in the redirect from /signin-facebook.

I decided to follow [this](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=magic%20restart) good old concept, and go back to the original template code. Pretty soon I figured out that I forgot to configure the new server. For instance, the folder the code refers to did not exist and the site had no permission to create it.

Obviously, that solved it.